# unable to install cordova in mac os X 10.10.5

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, cordova, cordova-plugins

when i install Cordova using command line in mac os X10.10.5 then i get the error!!!

> npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated
>   into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
>   /Users/winaimmac/bin/cordova ->
>   /Users/winaimmac/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova cordova@6.0.0
>   /Users/winaimmac/lib/node_modules/cordova ├── underscore@1.7.0 ├──
>   q@1.0.1 ├── ansi@0.3.1 ├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7) ├──
>   update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0,
>   string-length@1.0.1, chalk@1.1.1, repeating@1.1.3,
>   latest-version@1.0.1, configstore@1.4.0) └── cordova-lib@6.0.0
>   (valid-identifier@0.0.1, opener@1.4.1, properties-parser@0.2.3,
>   semver@4.3.6, nopt@3.0.6, dep-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, xcode@0.8.0,
>   tar@1.0.2, aliasify@1.9.0, init-package-json@1.9.3,
>   cordova-app-hello-world@3.10.0, npm@2.14.17, request@2.47.0,
>   cordova-serve@1.0.0, npmconf@2.1.2, cordova-js@4.1.3)

how to fix it
help me 
thanks

Comment: That is a warning, not an error. You can ignore ist.

Comment: but Cordova not installed?